# C/C++ source code parser using PYTHON

Tags: python, parsing

Could anyone point me an already available python snippet/script which can parse C/C++ code?

Basically I wanted to create an Class-to-Function() and Object-used-file-location-mapping etc., of a C/C++ source code using python, so that I can create a new level of abstraction of code in a script readable format, which can be used for Artificial Intelligence in the Code parsing..!

Comment: have you looked at flex and bison, you wont need to redo if it satisfies what you are trying to do

Comment: You could use `gcc` or `clang` to compile C/C++ code out of python. The generated shared objects (`.so`) or dynamic link libraries (`.dll`) might be linked/loaded at run-time.

Comment: sure Will look into flex/bison now! thanks for the response

Comment: These are the links I once used to make a C like compiler: [ANSI C grammar, Lex specification](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) and [ANSI C Yacc grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html). However, writing a C compiler (not to mention that C++ is much more complicated) is high effort. I'm still thinking that "embedding" an existing compiler is the more reasonable option.

Comment: I think the best and easiest path would probably be the one described in Kristina's answer.

But for future references, if one chooses to go the route of writing his own parser for C and/or C++, here are some pointers:

* [ANSI C Yacc grammar](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html)

* [C99 lex and yacc](https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/2933703)

* [C and C++98 yacc grammars](https://github.com/jessicah/becaml/tree/master/Traducteur/c-c%2B%2B-grammars-1.2)

* [many ANTLR grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) (containing ones also for C and C++14)

Answer (score 3):

`LLVM` built with `Clang` will produce `libclang` for you which, luckily, happens to have great Python bindings right out of the box. Get the latest LLVM and Clang from the releases page, the current stable one being [LLVM 6.0.0](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html). Make sure you have the appropriate Python development dependencies and build all of it. Then you can use Clang's `Tooling` to do all sorts of things to transform or modify your source code, [here's a good page to get you started](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang).

I would suggest using `Tooling` instead of a hand rolled or generated parser especially for C++ due to its complexity. The library however handles it for you and allows you to transform or introspect the produced AST, letting you build on top of that.

No one will generally provide a fully working solution to a complex problem like you've presented, you will have to do the bulk of the work yourself, but those resources are great if you want to get started.

Comment: That's a great pointer.. Thanks for the help Kristina...!!

Comment: I also found the "cscope CLI" will act as a stand alone callback tool, that could help me achieve the relationship map from a python AI logic..!![‎23-‎04-‎2018 16:49]  
it seems we can also use Cscope in the CLI mode rather interactive, some thing like call and get 
http://tailrandom.blogspot.in/2008/10/using-cscope-from-command-line.html